# Where should I post my question about network operators?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about why some mobile telephone companies charge subscribers on free apps usage.

Where should I post this question?

Comment: What sort of network operators? Mobile telephone companies?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Mobile telephone companies.

Comment: I fear there's no site in Stack Exchange network for those questions, you'll have to ask the operators themselves.

Comment: Nowhere.  Ask those operators why.

Comment: I can tell you why - the app is free but the usage is not.  You are using the operator's network to play the "free" game, thus using the resources of the operator.  They obviously feel like they should charge you for the usage.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Now if that's the case, what do developers mean when they say, you can use their messenger app for free ?
Do you pay the mobile telephone companies for usage of apps like Whatsapp in America or you pay the developers annually?

Comment: @samuel it's not the appropriate place to get into this discussion.  But the short answer is you are mixing 2 different concepts - the cost of the app, and the cost of the usage.  The developer gives you the app for free, but the developer has no control over the operator.  He is in no position to promise the usage is free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly there is no such site existing as a beta or graduated site. Sorry! You could find the appropriate proposal about telephone companies on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), where people propose sites that might turn successful such as Puzzling.SE and Mythology.SE.

If there is no such current proposal going on, make an account and get 50 free rep by verifying your email. And bravo, you got 50 free rep! You can then create your own proposal to make a site about Telephone Companies or the appropriate subject about your question.

Hope this helps you!